# htaccess: Rewrite to root index from subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite from all subfolders to the root folder with the following .htaccess in root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule   . index.html [L]
```

I have the following structure

```
index.html
existing-subfolder/
index.js
request.js
.htaccess
```

When I load:

```
www.domain.de/existing-subfolder
```

it rewrites to www.domain.de/index.html but i get errors from AJAX loading scripts, because the request url (i.e. "request.js") is now *www.domain.de/existing-subfolder/request.js*

When the subfolder is not existing (www.domain.de/not-existing-subfolder), everything works. The request url is now *www.domain.de/request.js*

Comment: So you want to rewrite `www.domain.de/existing-subfolder/request.js` to `www.domain.de/request.js` ?

Comment: i want to rewrite all subdomains to the root index.html wich it is doing well. But when a subdomain exists (`www.domain.de/existing-subfolder`), it shows `www.domain.de/existing-subfolder/` in the navigation bar and loads `www.domain.de/index.html`, but all relative ajax loading urls (`request.js`) from there are now from the subdomain(i.e. `www.domain.de/existing-subfolder/request.js`) and not from the root (`www.domain.de/request.js`). When the subdomain ist not existent, it works with no problem (i.e `www.domain.de/not-existing-subfolder`)

Comment: Add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`